# Утечка памяти при смене ориентации экрана

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, fragment-transaction

Помогите устранить утечку памяти при смене ориентации экрана.
Активити содержит два фрагмента, каждый из которых можно удалять, при нажатии на кнопку. Не могу сообразить как устранить утечку, возникающую при смене ориентации. Насколько я понял необходимо как-то зафиксировать фрагменты в активити. 
Утечка памяти из-за пересоздания активити не важна.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.robot.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.robot.test.fragments.ScrollingActivity;
import com.example.robot.test.fragments.item1;
import com.example.robot.test.fragments.item10;
import com.example.robot.test.fragments.item2;
import com.example.robot.test.fragments.item3;
import com.example.robot.test.fragments.item4;
import com.example.robot.test.fragments.item5;
import com.example.robot.test.fragments.item6;
import com.example.robot.test.fragments.item7;
import com.example.robot.test.fragments.item8;
import com.example.robot.test.fragments.item9;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    item1 it1;
    item2 it2;
    item3 it3;
    item4 it4;
    item5 it5;
    item6 it6;
    item7 it7;
    item8 it8;
    item9 it9;
    item10 it10;
    ScrollingActivity scA;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        it1 = new item1();
        it2 = new item2();
        it3 = new item3();
        it4 = new item4();
        it5 = new item5();
        it6 = new item6();
        it7 = new item7();
        it8 = new item8();
        it9 = new item9();
        it10 = new item10();
        scA = new ScrollingActivity();

//        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.Delete_fragment1) {
            ft.remove(it8);
        }
        if (id == R.id.Delete_fragment2) {
            ft.remove(it1);
        }
        ft.commit();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (id == R.id.nav_item1) {
            ft.replace(R.id.containter, it1);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_item2) {
            ft.replace(R.id.containter, it2);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_item3) {
            ft.replace(R.id.containter, it3);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_item4) {
            ft.replace(R.id.containter, it4);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_item5) {
            ft.replace(R.id.containter, it5);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_item6) {
            ft.replace(R.id.containter, it6);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_item7) {
            ft.replace(R.id.containter, it7);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_item8) {
            ft.replace(R.id.containter, it8); // тут и получаю два фрагмента в одном активити
            ft.add(R.id.containter,it1);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_item9) {
            ft.replace(R.id.containter, it9);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_item10) {
            ft.replace(R.id.containter, it10);
        } ft.commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

1 фрагмент

```
package com.example.robot.test.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.robot.test.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link item1.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link item1#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class item1 extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public item1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment item1.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static item1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        item1 fragment = new item1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Log.d("qqq","item1 "+this);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item1, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

2 фрагмент

```
package com.example.robot.test.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.robot.test.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link item8.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link item8#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class item8 extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public item8() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment item8.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static item8 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        item8 fragment = new item8();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Log.d("qqq","item8 "+this);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item8, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: выложите код, чтобы понять в чем проблема

Comment: Что это и зачем? `scA = new ScrollingActivity();`

Comment: На это можно не обращать внимание, дело точно не в этом.

Comment: О какой утечке идет речь? У вас какая-то ошибка возникает? Стектрейс покажите. Если вам leakCanary (например) говорит об утечке, расскажите и нам, что течет... По коду сложно понять что у вас течет, видно лишь, что mListener вы не назначаете, но к утечке отношения это не имеет.